# при наведении на ссылку в меню двигается нижерасположенный контент

Tags: html, css

http://learning-verstka.esy.es/

box-sizing: border-box; - проставлен как у пп меню, так и у всего блока навигации.

Что я сделала не так?

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: У вас на этой странице http://learning-verstka.esy.es/   меню не закрыто, а закомментирован последний пункт вместе с закрывающим тегом </ul>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ссылки у вас применен `margin: 20px;`, а при наведении вы добавляете еще и `padding-bottom: 18px;`, то есть суммарный отступ снизу получается 38px. Для решения вашей проблемы нужно убрать нижний magrin:

```
.nav ul li a:hover, a.login:hover {
    magrin-bottom: 0;  
}
```

А также для ссылки увеличить margin на 1px:

```
.nav ul li a, a.login {
    margin: 21px;
}
```

или при наведении уменьшить padding на 1px:

```
.nav ul li a:hover, a.login:hover {
    padding-bottom: 17px;
}
```

Так как вы добавляете border 3px!

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ Спасибо! *убежал править по инструкциям. По факту - отпишусь.

Еще раз СПАСИБО!

Comment: ВЫЛЕЧИЛОСЬ!!! Значит, все дело было в неаккуратно расставленных отступах...

СПАСИБО!!!!

Answer (score 2):

По наведению на элемент к нему добавляются следующие стили:

```
border-bottom: 3px solid #1abc9c;
padding-bottom: 18px;
```

Что дает дополнительно 21пкс к высоте. Самим элементом является `a`, у которого `display: inline`, и никакой `box-sizing` к нему поэтому не применен.